# Can I use multiple metadata tags in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, metadata

Is there a way to apply multiple metadata tags to a single property of an ActionScript class?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply multiple metadata tags to a property of a class just by listing them one after the other, before the property declaration.  Like this:

```
[Bindable] 
[Transient]
public var attribute: Object;
```

Comment: You're first impulse was to post a question instead of try it?  Or look at Flex Framework code that does stuff like this all the time?

Comment: Pray demonstrate your superior google-fu: [https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple+metadata+tags+actionscript](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple+metadata+tags+actionscript)

Comment: I didn't say anything about searching for it.  Since the question and answer were posted at about the same time was your purpose in posting in order to make this searchable?  Or did you post because you thought it was easier than testing yourself?

Comment: Even after testing it, I have no way of knowing if what I've done is safe.  Maybe there's some secret gotcha I don't know about?  So yes, my post had two purposes: to get further clarification on the correct way to do this, and to make this question more visible to other people who might be googling away.

Comment: @Reboog711 what's the big deal? StackOverflow invites you to answer your own question to share knowledge, there's even a checkbox to answer automatically when creating a question.

Comment: @veehmot The question "Is there a way of doing something like this?" and the answer "It works as is" don't seem like they'll help anyone.  Both very so poorly written.

Comment: @Veehmot There; I rewrote both the question and the answer so they are more direct; and better suited to StackOverflow